# Java: raise event if method was not called for specific amount of time

Tags: java, concurrency

In a concurrent environment, multiple threads call a method. After the method has not been called for some time (e.g. 5 seconds), an idle event should be called.

After 5 more seconds without the method being called, the idle event should not be called again. The idle timer should be started again after the first method call.

```
public class Service {
    public void do(Foo foo) {
        // process foo
    }

    private void onIdle() {
    }
}
```

What is a safe and efficient way to implement this?

If this can be done much better without the second requirement (not calling onIdle() again and again), then this would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the concerns. Let the service keep state about being called and have another thread poll the idle method:

```
public class Service {
    private volatile long lastActivity;
    public void do(Foo foo) {
        // process foo
        lastActivity = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private void onIdle() {
        if (lastActivity > 0 && System.currentTimeMillis() - lastActivity > 5000) {
            // do stuff
            lastActivity = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Then have task run every 5 seconds in another thread that simply does:

```
public void run() {
    service.onIdle();
}
```

You can schedule the task using whatever your environment provides out of the box (eg Spring’s `@Scheduled`) or create your own thread that just sleeps 5 seconds after calling onIdle() in a `while (true)` Koop.

Comment: although this solution results in possibly unnecessary checks every 5 seconds, I prefer this answer for its simplicity.

Comment: @RüdigerSchulz it also means you can temporarily turn off polling without affecting the Service, or change the way it’s polled etc. let the Service focus on the being a Service, and the polling action be a polling action.